# How to get childNodes after parsing a string as XML using xdmp.unquote

Tags: marklogic, child-nodes

I am trying to get the childNodes after parsing an XML string using something like:

```js
fn.head(xdmp.unquote('<wrapper><e1>this is <b>e1</b></e1><e2>this is <b>e2</b></e2></wrapper>')).childNodes
```

I don't think this is the right way of doing this as I am getting the following output:

```
<wrapper><e1>this is <b>e1</b></e1><e2>this is <b>e2</b></e2></wrapper>
```

Could someone please help me with the right way of getting the child nodes of an XML string ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Were you expecting to select the `/wrapper` element or the `/wrapper/e1` and `/wrapper/e2` elements?

If you wanted to return the `wrapper` element:

```
fn.head(xdmp.unquote('<wrapper><e1>this is <b>e1</b></e1><e2>this is <b>e2</b></e2></wrapper>'))
  .root
```

or

```
fn.head(xdmp.unquote('<wrapper><e1>this is <b>e1</b></e1><e2>this is <b>e2</b></e2></wrapper>'))
  .xpath("/wrapper")
```

If you wanted to return the childNodes of the `wrapper` element:

```
fn.head(xdmp.unquote('<wrapper><e1>this is <b>e1</b></e1><e2>this is <b>e2</b></e2></wrapper>'))
  .root.childNodes
```

or

```
fn.head(xdmp.unquote('<wrapper><e1>this is <b>e1</b></e1><e2>this is <b>e2</b></e2></wrapper>'))
  .xpath("/wrapper/*")
```